# ActionBarSherlock Custom Home Image not Showing

Tags: android, xml, actionbarsherlock

So I found a solution to setting multiple different home buttons throughout an app by setting the homeAsUpIndicator xml value like this:

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
```

and setting the logo in code with setLogo(...);

My problem is that the logo only shows in certain situations, here is one that doesn't work:

```
public class DiscountActivity extends SherlockActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_discount);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.back_x);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    View actionView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nextlist_bar, null);
    TextView title = (TextView) actionView.findViewById(R.id.nextbar_title);
    title.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Establishment"));
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionView, params);
    actionBar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
}
}
```

Working situation:

```
public class NextListActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next_list);
    con = NextListActivity.this;

    layout_MainMenu = (FrameLayout) findViewById( R.id.dimmer);
    layout_MainMenu.getForeground().setAlpha( 0);

    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
    favorites = gson.fromJson(appSharedPrefs.getString("Favorites", ""), type);
    if (favorites == null) favorites = new ArrayList<String>();

    mPager = (NonScrollablePager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    curLoc = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("CurLoc");
    clickedItem = new ViewHolder("", "", "", "", R.drawable.bandus, "", "");
    nextTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("NextTitle");

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.back_arrow);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nextlist_bar, null);
    TextView title = (TextView) actionView.findViewById(R.id.nextbar_title);
    title.setText(nextTitle);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionView, params);
    actionBar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
}
}
```

Can anyone help me understand my problem? :)

Comment: can you show the situation where it works

Comment: yes but there are a lot more variables which will have to be ignored